# How to add external jar into build.sbt from windows system path

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-assembly

I am trying to add external jar in my build.sbt from Windows path. It was working properly in my Linux system with below dependencies:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
"com.sample.Test" %% "TestClass" % "0.0.1" from "file:///home/user/jars/sample.jar"
)
```

but now I want to migrate that to Windows system where I am getting issue w.r.t to Path.
Could you help me to pass Windows External jar path in build.sbt correctly.

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
"com.sample.Test" %% "TestClass" % "0.0.1" from "file:///E:/jars/sample.jar"
)
```

I have also tried with path `"E:/jars/sample.jar"` but it is also not working.